# Receipts Sent to Customer for Current Donation Include Previous Donations

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, custom-fields, message-templates, system-workflow-messages

Ok, I'm hoping I can explain this so it makes some sort of sense :)

In CiviCRM, we have a customer who has custom profile fields that donors can enter the amount of their contribution that they want to go to a specific cause
[image]

The issue is that the receipt is including the contribution the donor just made as well as the previous amount(s) they chose to designate the last time they made a contribution (since it's the same donor with the same email address).
[image]

Is there any way to remove the amount from the previous contribution the donor made? It's not helpful for our customer because they don't know what amount/designation applies to what year when they view the receipt that's sent and the customers are concerned that they are being charged twice.

Any help with this would be GREATLY appreciated because this is one of our my vocal customers. :)

If you need any additional information, please let me know.

Thank You,
Nicole

- DRUPAL 7
- CIVICRM 4.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom fields that allow you to specify who the donation should go to should most likely be attached to the contribution, not the contact.  Change the data model and the receipts should fix themselves.

Comment: Ok, so, just to clarify: when creating those designation fields, our customer should create the custom fields and select "Contributions" for the "Used For" section instead of "individual", correct? I just want to make sure that I'm giving them the correct information :)